# How to call a "file" function of Text.BibTeX.Parse?

Tags: haskell

I'm having a little difficulty navigating all the haskell docs..

I want to call the `file` function from the [Text.BibTeX.Parse module](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bibtex/0.0.6.1/doc/html/Text-BibTeX-Parse.html) in haskell, but I can't figure out where to get the `Parser` argument:

```
file :: Parser [T]
```

I know it comes from the Parsec module, but when I [look there](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.1.1/doc/html/Text-Parsec-String.html#t%3aParser), I have no idea what the `numbers` variable in the example code of `parseFromFile` refers to:

```
main    = do{ result <- parseFromFile numbers "digits.txt"
              ; case result of
                  Left err  -> print err
                  Right xs  -> print (sum xs)
              }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to produce a `Parser` argument to use `file`: it already is a `Parser`! The variable `numbers` in the Parsec documentation is probably standing in for whatever parser you want to run on the text in `"digits.txt"`. So, in your case, that's the `file` parser; you'd use `file` instead of `numbers`.

Comment: Thanks, I confused `file` for a function that takes a parser - not returns one, haha.